# TTY not work after X starts

Tags: linux, xorg, console

I have a HP Envy4 5306tx laptop with Intel+Nvidia dual cards, and I install fedora 19 X64 on it without NVidia proprietory driver. However, there are some problems about the X and TTY。

- The TTYs are normal and switchable through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, when booting with runlevel 3.
- When X starts, I cannot switch to any TTY. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, I get a blank screen(black/grey/blue), and cannot go back to X.
- When I exit Windows manager, I also get a blank screen. And I have to press power key to poweroff.

There are some errors in `Xorg.0.conf`:

```
[26.217] (EE) Failed to load module "glamoregl" (module does not exist, 0)
[26.448] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[26.461] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
```

There are also some errors in `/var/log/messages`:

- Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Consolekit': time out
- [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'

How that happens? Is it related to the dual cards?

Comment: try `sudo mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts`

Comment: @SHW,

  devpts is already mounted or /dev/pts busy
  devpts is already mounted on /dev/pts

Comment: Fedora uses tty1 for xorg.

Comment: Which GPU is the monitor connected to?

Comment: I dont know which GPU being used. Since no proprietory driver is installed. I guess the system uses Intel GPU, because `glxinfo` shows an open source GL driver is used in renderng. @Gilles

Comment: It doesnot matter which TTY is used for Xorg. Even I manually run `startx` from TTY2 in runlevel 3, the problems remain. @enedil

Comment: Try to blacklist intel graphics, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253326/nixos-no-login-prompt-in-virtual-terminals .  But in case of laptop I guess this will have impact on power consumption.